# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Web.config transform question

Tags: asp.net, web-config, visual-web-developer, one-click-web-publishing

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to force Visual Web Developer 2010 Express to use my Web.Release.config when I'm publishing my web application.  I'm using FTP to publish my webapp to a remote server.  Each time I publish, the build uses my Web.Debug.config.

I know I'm overlooking something simple and would really appreciate a clue.

Respectfully,

Ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Web Developer Express (2010), selecting the build is simply a matter of clicking on the drop down to the right of the green "Start Debugging" button.  Debug will use your debug web.config and release will use your release web.config.

When publishing, click the drop down and select Release.  Then publish as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Build -> Configuration Manager`

Under `Active Solution Configuration` select **Release**

***Hopefully this is what you're after.***

Comment: I think your instructions are applicable for VS2010, not VWD2010 Express.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Correcting you, go to Tools -> Settings and click Expert Settings. Then under Build -> Configuration Manager is there.